# UI For My Ubuntu Machine

Tags: gui, vnc, tightvncserver, vncviewer

I'm running an Ubuntu server with Digital Ocean. I want full UI access, like a personal computer, however this is hard. I have a VNC server running. When I connect, the only way I can open windows, is if I manually go into the Digital Ocean and run a command to open GUI, like `firefox`. Is there a way I can get a taskbar? A terminal window? Shortcuts?

###### Thanks!

Comment: One thing that I use for Raspberry Pi's (on my local network), is I will install XFCE (`sudo apt install xfce4`) and a remote desktop server (`sudo apt install xrdp`), reboot the machine (`sudo reboot now`), and then connect to the Pi over remote desktop. But if this server is publicly exposed, that isn't a good thing to do.

Comment: @cocomac They aren't asking about that. They already have VNC.

Comment: @UCYT5040 However it's not clear that they have a desktop environment installed. OP, if there is no DE, you should review a few things. First, if your server does not have robust resources, installing a DE will significantly tax those resources. Also, if you are running services on that server, consider the fact that installing a DE could impact the stability of your server compared to not running a DE, especially if you do not have a lot of system resources to support it.